# Dynamic Configuration of Root URL in ABP Framework: Obtaining Current Root URL for Production Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, abp

I'm currently working on ABP framework and I want to set the `Root.Url` dynamically depending on where the is running app on the HostModule, so I read some questions related, and they said you need to add to your `App.Settings` file like:

```
"App": {
    "ClientUrl": "http://localhost:4200"
    }
```

Then in the Host module, change it as:

```
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
      Configure<AppUrlOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Applications["Angular"].RootUrl = configuration["App:ClientUrl"];
        options.Applications["Angular"].Urls[AccountUrlNames.PasswordReset] = "account/reset-password";
    });
    }
```

But this is static, so if I publish to production when I generate an url it comes as: localhost://.... etc, but I want to get the current root url. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you break it down ? What is the mean of  "if I publish to production when I generate an url it comes as: localhost://.... etc, but I want to get the current root url"

Comment: As you can see I change the password reset link, so if user receive a reset password link in their email on production, the link is composed as http://localhost://.../account/reset-password?.. instead http://mydomain/account/reset-password?... @TeomanTıngır

Comment: Can you provide your email template and also double check your production appsettings ? Also the production environment. There might be possibility it still uses your development configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea would be to create separate configuration files for different environments.
For example, create in addition of your default `appsettings.json` for development a separate `appsettings.Production.json` for production.

`appsettings.json`:

```json
{
    "App": {
        "ClientUrl": "http://localhost:4200"
    }
}
```

`appsettings.Production.json`:

```json
{
    "App": {
        "ClientUrl": "https://yourproductiondomain.com"
    }
}
```

In your startup class, make sure to add the following line to configure the app to use the correct `appsettings` file based on the environment:

```cs
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

That means you can continue to use the configuration in the Host module as you have in your example, but it will now pull the correct value based on the environment:

```cs
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    Configure<AppUrlOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Applications["Angular"].RootUrl = configuration["App:ClientUrl"];
        options.Applications["Angular"].Urls[AccountUrlNames.PasswordReset] = "account/reset-password";
    });
}
```

All you need to do, when deploying your application, is to set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Production`.
This can usually be done in the settings of your hosting provider or by setting the environment variable in the operating system where the application is hosted.
See also "[Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0)".

This approach ensures that your application uses the correct settings based on the environment it is running in, allowing you to dynamically configure the root URL and other settings as needed.